# search for string embedded in {} after keyword

Tags: python, regex

How can I get the string embedded in `{}` after a keyword, where the number of characters between the keyword and the braces `{}` is unknown. *e.g.:*

```
includegraphics[x=2]{image.pdf}
```

the keyword would be includegraphics and the string to be found is image.pdf, but the text in between `[x=2]` could have anything between the two `[]`. 
So I want to ignore all characters between the keyword and `{` or I want to ignore everything between `[]`

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do. If you just want to extract image.pdf you could use an indexOf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall`

```
>>> sample = 'includegraphics[x=2]{image.pdf}'
>>> re.findall('includegraphics.*?{(.*?)}',sample)
['image.pdf']
```

**Explanation**:

The [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) deals with regular expressions in Python. Its [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method is useful to find all occurences of a pattern in a string.

A regular expression for the pattern you are interested in is `'includegraphics.*?{(.*?)}'`. Here `.` symbolizes "any character", while the `*` means 0 or more times. The question mark makes this a non-greedy operation. From the documentation:

> The `*`, `+`, and `?` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much
>   text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE
>   `<.*>` is matched against `<H1\>title</H1>`, it will match the entire
>   string, and not just `<H1>`. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it
>   perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters
>   as possible will be matched. Using `.*?` in the previous expression will
>   match only `<H1>`.

Please note that while in your case using `.*?` should be fine, in general it's better to use more specialized character groups such as `\w` for alphanumerics and `\d` for digits, when you know what the content is going to consist of in advance.

Comment: Or better, use the [*unrolling the loop*](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) technique that will let you handle very large input texts. However, something makes me think negated character classes should work much better here. Have a look at [`includegraphics[^{]*{([^}]*)}`](https://regex101.com/r/lO5aJ7/1).

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.search`

```
re.search(r'includegraphics\[[^\[\]]*\]\{([^}]*)\}', s).group(1)
```